# Would there be alien involvement in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

After the release of *Guardians of the Galaxy* movie, Marvel Cinematic Universe is now rich in aliens. Would there be any alien involvement in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*? Any official statement or leak?

Comment: There is at least one alien involved, he is named Thor.

Comment: @JackBNimble - I think I've heard of him.

Comment: Define alien involvement. Rumors are that Ultron was created in part from Chitauri wreckage from the Battle of NY.

Comment: @phantom42 Ironman created him.

Comment: According to promo art, [Ultron's original program is from the Chitauri](http://io9.com/avengers-2-art-reveals-ultrons-new-origin-story-1676484607). It appears Tony fleshes it out and gives it a body.

Comment: @phantom42 Okay, then it'll do. It can be said alien involvement..

Comment: @phantom42 Aw man, that's a bummer. "Evil alien tech is evil" isn't nearly as cool an origin as "A hero's brilliant creation turns against him."  Still, I imagine they'll make it work.

Comment: @SS ... No, it wasn't Ironman who created Ultron, it was what was left in Loki's shorts after Hulk got through with him ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous to the release of the movie, [leaked toy art](http://io9.com/avengers-2-art-reveals-ultrons-new-origin-story-1676484607). indicated a possible alien connection to Ultron.

According to the toy packagin, Ultron's original program is found amongst the ruins of the Chitauri attack in NY. Tony works with it and fleshes it out into a fully realized AI, resulting in the villain Ultron.

[image: ultron bio]

> **"First discovered as a simple computer program hidden among the ruins of the Chitauri invasion of New York, the being known as Ultron soon completed its development into a sophisticated artificial intelligence after some experimentation by Tony Stark.** Ultron's first shocking ultimatum upon gaining consciousness was to declare the human race its enemy. Setting out to exterminate all life on the planet, the unstable and emotional Ultron seeks to upgrade its mechanical body to an ultimate, unstoppable form. With an army of robotic drones and the ability to enter and corrupt any computer network, Ultron will stop at nothing to see humanity wiped out."

However, as we learned in the final cut of the movie, the leaked art is close, but not *entirely* accurate.

Ultron is created using

> "code" found in the gem of Loki's scepter, which was lost during the Battle of New York.

However, we learn that

> the gem in Loki's scepter is actually an Infinity Stone,

meaning that the creation of Ultron has nothing to do with the Chitauri (aside from them being involved in the battle that brought the scepter to Earth), but is easily argued as being alien-based. There is, however, no direct alien *involvement* in the movie,

> unless you count Thanos, who appears to be attempting to manipulate events surrounding the Mind Stone.

Comment: Why does Tony need to use a Chitauri program to build an AI when he already has Jarvis?

Comment: @KSmarts No clue. My guess is that he's just trying to come up with something more advanced - because Tony Stark.

Comment: JARVIS is capable of conversation, but he seems to be more like an advanced Siri.  For example, he doesn't seem to have any personality or desires beyond executing Tony's instructions.  I imagine, when Vision appears, it'll become clear that JARVIS wasn't a true AI.

Comment: @KSmarts "Experimentation" could mean any number of things.  One possibility is that Stark was just trying to learn more about the Chitauri, and the AI evolved on its own

Comment: Ultron was created by Tony. Computational Matrix of the mind stone was able to execute it..